# cx_oracle executemany is not inserting all fields

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I am trying to use cx_oracle executemany to bulk insert rows into an Oracle database table.

My problem is executemany is 'skipping' certain fields without throwing an error and I'm tearing my hair out trying to  understand why.

The values I want to insert are stored in a list:

```
print (parsed_results[0]) 
['100700000005', '00000005006', '20180223', 'Transaction Deposit 1', '1', '', 'N'] 
print (parsed_results[1])
['100700000005', '00000005006', '20180223', 'Transaction Deposit 2', '1', '', 'N'] 
etc
```

If I loop through the list and insert them one at a time, everything works fine. However when I use executemany certain fields are skipped almost randomly.

code:

```
connectString = 'user/password@{dba}'.format(dba=dbname)
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(connectString)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.arraysize = 5000
s_sql_insert = '''INSERT INTO My_Schema.My_table(
    ID, ACCT_ID, DATE, TYPE,COUNT, REF_NO, REV) 
    VALUES (:ID, :ACCT_ID, :DATE, :TRAN, :COUNT, :REF_NO, :REV)'''

try:
    cursor.prepare(s_sql_insert)
except Exception as e: 
    logging.error ('Failed to prepare cursor!')
    logging.error('Reason: %s', e)

try:
    cursor.executemany(None, (parsed_results))
except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as e:
    logging.error ('Failed to insert rows!')
    logging.error('Reason: %s', e)
connection.commit()
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Does anyone know why this is happening or how I can get more information on any errors?

Comment: Are you sure **every** item in *parsed_results* have same length of 7? Carefully check *random skips* as params are passed by position. And anything in log files?

Comment: Looping through the list row by row and doing cursor.execute(s_sql_insert, (row)) works fine.  I think something about the dataset in parsed_results is upsetting executemany

Comment: And no exceptions recorded in log files with row by row `execute` and `executemany`? How many rows are we talking about? Did you really run through **all** rows or just filtered subset rows?

Comment: What version of cx_Oracle are you using? Can you provide a complete case that demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 4):

Possibly it may be due to named vs numbered parameters. Consider adjusting prepared statement to numbered placeholders:

```
s_sql_insert = '''INSERT INTO My_Schema.My_table(
    ID, ACCT_ID, DATE, TYPE,COUNT, REF_NO, REV) 
    VALUES (:1, :2, :3, :4, :5, :6, :7)'''
```

Alternatively, transform *parsed_results* into a list of dictionaries to map to named placeholders. You can do so with a dictionary comprehension:

```
parse_results_dict = [{'ID': i[0],
                       'ACCT_ID' : i[1], 
                       'DATE': i[2], 
                       'TRAN': i[3],
                       'COUNT': i[4], 
                       'REF_NO': i[5], 
                       'REV': i[6]} for i in parse_results]


s_sql_insert = '''INSERT INTO My_Schema.My_table(
    ID, ACCT_ID, DATE, TYPE, COUNT, REF_NO, REV) 
    VALUES (:ID, :ACCT_ID, :DATE, :TRAN, :COUNT, :REF_NO, :REV)'''

cursor.prepare(s_sql_insert)
cursor.executemany(None, parsed_results_dict)
connection.commit()
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this, you are first doing `cursor.prepare(statement)` which according to the docs:

```
This can be used before a call to execute() to define the statement 
that will be executed. When this is done, the prepare phase will not be 
performed when the call to execute() is made with None or the same 
string object as the statement.
```

When you call execute in your code you specifically use `None` which means your prepared statement won't be used.

Just execute your statement within the `executemany` function call. Also to see errors you can the `batcherrors=True` flag in your `cursor.executemany` call so you can follow it with a `cursor.getbatcherrors()` to retrieve all the errors. This is all straight from the docs.

Comment: Where is the docs for this? Per this [Oracle tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/prez-python-queries-101587.html), `None` can be used after `prepare`. See end of *Bind Variable Patterns* section in link.

Comment: Prepare(statement) and executemany(None,  ) is not the problem. I've used them successfully in the past

Comment: There is a newer tutorial at https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/tree/master/samples/tutorial